# Showing that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt[i]{i!}}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have to show that the sum: $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[i]{i!}}$ converges.

I tried to use the fact that $e^x \geq \dfrac{x^n}{n!}$(by considering Taylor series) because then we get for $x=n$ that : $$ n! \geq \left(\dfrac{n}{e}\right)^n \Leftrightarrow \sqrt[n]{n!} \geq \dfrac{n}{e} \Leftrightarrow \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[i]{i!}} \leq \dfrac{e}{i} \Leftrightarrow \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[i]{i!}} \leq \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{e}{i}$$
but $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{e}{i}$ diverges so it didn't help me..

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there a reason you think it converges?

Comment: $n!\leqslant n^n.$

Comment: Assuming $n$ denotes a natural number, you wrote a finite sum. Therefore there is no question of convergence.

Answer (score 3):

The series $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt[i]{i!}}$, **as $n$ goes to infinity**, does not converge, instead, it diverges.

HINT: For each positive integer $i$, $$i! < i^i.$$
Thus, taking the $\frac{1}{i}$-th roots of each side of this gives the inequality:
$$\sqrt[i]{i!} < \sqrt[i]{i^i} = i.$$
Thus, the inequality $\frac{1}{\sqrt[i]{i!}} > \frac{1}{i}$ holds for each positive integer $i$. So on that note, what do we know about $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i}$ again?